# Write pandas data as html format inside a Html.Div

Tags: python, html, pandas, html-table, plotly-dash

I am web scraping a html table, i am able to read the table, now i just need to write back in my page.
So i need return it inside a html.Div() and see it as a real table

```
def table():
URL = "https://www.infrontanalytics.com/fe-en/BMG5876H1051/Marvell-Technology-Group-Ltd-/beta"
        tables = pd.read_html(URL)
        print("There are : ",len(tables)," tables")
        print("Take look at table 0")
        print(tables[7])
        htmlout = html.Div(tables[7].to_html())
        return htmlout
```

The result i see on the web-page is the written table with the tags, but i need the visual table:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe"> <thead> <tr style="text-align: right;"> <th></th> <th>Company Name</th> <th>Ctry</th> <th>MarketCap.last (mUSD)</th> <th>Beta1-Year</th> <th>Year-To-DatePrice Change(in local currency)</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <th>0</th> <td>Marvell Technology Grou...</td> <td>BMU</td> <td>29 073</td> <td>1.40</td> <td>63.3%</td> </tr> <tr> <th>1</th> <td>International Peers Median</td> <td>International Peers Median</td> <td>International Peers Median</td> <td>1.26</td> <td>42.1%</td> </tr> <tr> <th>2</th> <td>NXP Semiconductors NV</td> <td>NLD</td> <td>45 876</td> <td>1.26</td> <td>28.9%</td> </tr> <tr> <th>3</th> <td>Silicon Motion Technolo...</td> <td>CYM</td> <td>1 561</td> <td>0.94</td> <td>-12.4%</td> </tr> <tr> <th>4</th> <td>QUALCOMM Inc.</td> <td>USA</td> <td>178 268</td> <td>1.20</td> <td>78.6%</td> </tr> <tr> <th>5</th> <td>STMicroelectronics NV</td> <td>NLD</td> <td>36 873</td> <td>1.48</td> <td>42.1%</td> </tr> <tr> <th>6</th> <td>NVIDIA Corp.</td> <td>USA</td> <td>335 702</td> <td>1.36</td> <td>130.5%</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>
```

How can I transform the tags i got from pandas in html format to return it in a html page?
I used the to_html() function but it doesn't work as i expected.

Comment: Hi, if you are trying to use Plotly, you should look at this page : https://plotly.com/python/table/ (section "Tables in Dash").
It seems that Plotly doesn't use html directly but Pandas dataframe converted in dict. Otherwise, Plotly renders your html as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons you can't insert raw HTML into dash elements. You options are either to convert your dataframe manually into an `html.Table` element, containing `html.Tr`, `html.Td` etc., or – much better – use the [Dash DataTable component](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable).

In your case this would look something like this:

```
def table():
    URL = "https://www.infrontanalytics.com/fe-en/BMG5876H1051/Marvell-Technology-Group-Ltd-/beta"
    tables = pd.read_html(URL)
    print("There are : ",len(tables)," tables")
    print("Take look at table 0")
    print(tables[7])
    df = tables[7]
    htmlout = html.Div(dash_table.DataTable(
        id='table',
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
    ))
    return htmlout
```

Don't forget to import:

```
import dash_table
```